Statistical Test for Unequal Questions for each Variable
The quantitative research we are doing is testing the correlation between the independent variable and dependent variable. For our questionnaire, we have collected demographic data (sex, age and year level), which may not be relevant to my question. We utilize the Likert Scale for our researcher-made questionnaire. It has 5 questions for the independent variable and 10 questions for the dependent variable. It has passed the reliability test. The data is not paired.
I want to know if it is possible to test the correlation between these variables? If it is possible, what statistical tests could we use?
Below is an example of our data with 10 respondents. Thank you so much!


Hello @SuinegAsac and welcome on CrossValidated. Can you clarify what you mean by "Our questionnaire has 5 questions for the independent variable and 10 questions for the dependent variable"? It would be helpful to explain what those questions are, their nature (are they categorical? continuous? ordinal?) , and what is the research question you're trying to answer ultimately.

In particular, the fact that you have more than 2 questions is a strong indication that you have more than 2 variables. This is unless you used some particular method to combine these multiple questions into two variables, but that's not clear at all from your question, and you should clarify that too.

Our research study is a quantitative research, wherein we used the Likert Scale for those questions.

It would be really helpful if you provided much more context than that. The more information you withhold, the more difficult it will be to give you a relevant and correct answer. Are all the questions on a likert scale, including the independant variables? Don't you have demographic data, like gender or age? Are your data paired, i.e. are some questions measuring something before and after an intervention? etc. No need to answer in comments, you can edit your question to add information, with the "edit" link available just under the question and above the comment section.

Thanks for the editing. I voted to reopen the question, now let's wait and see if others think there is still missing information to give you an answer.

"All I know is that the number of questions for each variable should be equal" - from a statistical point of view I see no reason why this has to be so. Where do you "know" this from?

Your wording looks like sex, age and year level play no role in this question, and it's just about independent vs. dependent variable. Maybe you say this explicitly in the question, or otherwise explain what use you make of the additional variables.

What reliability test are you referring to? I've never heard of a reliability "test", only metrics like Cronbach's alpha, ICC, etc.

Hello @ShawnHemelstrand. The reliability test we did is a test-retest to see if our questionnaire yields reliable results over time. We had 10 respondents, excluded from the sample, answer our questionnaire two times with a two-week gap between. We then used the CORREL function in excel to see the level of reliability for each of our variables.

I see. It may help others with your issue about the "unequal questions" by supplying an example table or a screenshot of your data in some way. That way it may be easier to envision what is going on. It may also be helpful to supply the Excel doc and how you calculated the correlation, that way it is clear why you arrived at this problem. As it stands, we are probably all applying more guesswork than needed.

Given that you use Likert-scale items in your questionaire, I assume that you collect ratings on two different themes, which you refer to as independent and dependent variable, which is somewhat misleading as these terms are usually used in an experimental context. I assume you really only have observational data, which you would like to correlate. Now, I further assume that (other than what you say in your question) you do not want to correlate the individual items but really the underlying constructs. If you were to correlate the individual items, you could do this by computing a 15x15 covariance matrix. Since Likert-scale items are ordinal data, you should choose a non-parametric correlation measure like Spearman's rank correlation. Still, I believe that you are interested in the association between the two underlying constructs. The good way to adress this question is a structural equation model, in which you model the factor structure of both questionnaires as well as a latent correlation. Make sure to model the ordinal scale correctly. The lavaan package for R is freely available and would be a great way to estimate such a correlated factors model with ordinal observations (e.g., using DWLS estimator with polychoric correlations for the ordinal variables).
